# C++ Casablanca, cant compile in Visual Studio Express 2013 Desktop Safeint3.hpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, casablanca

so i installed the Casablanca SDK for my project for some json useage.
So far so good but when im trying to build my project im getting the following errors :

```
Fehler 9 error C1004: Unerwartetes Dateiende gefunden. C:\sumo-0.20.0 - VS13\build\msvc11\packages\cpprestsdk.2.0.1\build\native\include\compat\safeint3.hpp 6237 1 z_libmicrosim_output
Fehler 7 error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ')' C:\sumo-0.20.0 - VS13\build\msvc11\packages\cpprestsdk.2.0.1\build\native\include\compat\safeint3.hpp 6237 1 z_libmicrosim_output
Fehler 6 error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ',' vor ')' C:\sumo-0.20.0 - VS13\build\msvc11\packages\cpprestsdk.2.0.1\build\native\include\compat\safeint3.hpp 6237 1 z_libmicrosim_output
Fehler 8 error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ';' vor '{' C:\sumo-0.20.0 - VS13\build\msvc11\packages\cpprestsdk.2.0.1\build\native\include\compat\safeint3.hpp 6237 1 z_libmicrosim_output
```

Sorry that its german but its basically some syntax error like missing "," before ")"

So am i doing something wrong? im not even using the safeint stuff as far as i know. Im just using the json and the http stuff. Did anyone had trouble with this before?
I did some research now but i can absolutely not find anything. I think its kind of strange that im getting syntax error in that project..

As you can see its the newest version and i installed it with nuget

im using Visual Studio Express 2013 Windows Desktop and Windows 7 if thats interesting..

Answer (score 0):

Ok i finally figured it out. Im new to C++ and didnt now that the order of the includes is important.. so i put the casablanca includes at the beginning and it works. Kind of strange i think but ok.